# form is null error in firebug while submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-submit

I am getting the values from database using json format and displaying them in a table. I want the users to go through the data and enter a new field called city. So I added a form in the same table. The problem is that the form is not being submitted.

```
$('table').append('
    <tr><td>' + element.id + '</td><td>' + element.aid + '</td><td>' + element.aname +
    '</td></td>' + '</td><td>' + element.acountry +  '</td><td>' + element.trips +
    '</td><td>' + element.comments + '</td><td>' + element.likes + '</td>
    <td>

    <form action="storecity.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="id" value="' + element.id + '" >
        <input type="text" name="city" value="">
        </td><td>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </form>
    </td></tr>');
```

When I use form.submit() - I get form is null in firebug. I tried submitting the form using ajax post request but still not working

Comment: This is why I use templates.

Comment: could you show how you're using `form.submit()`?

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="form.submit()">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form automatically fills in the closing form tag prematurely to where you placed it as the  is in the way.

The

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

is not being included in the form, which is a problem. You can try using a td that spans two cells and includes the entire form within a single `<td></td>`